# CakePHP: missing argument error, passing arguments via URL

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my controller (unfinished obviously but to "do some magic" I first need to make it run):

```
    public function add($customer_id, $question_set_id, $order_value) {

        $customer_id = $this->params['url']['customer_id'];
        $question_set_id = $this->params['url']['question_set_id'];
        $order_value = $this->params['url']['order_value'];

        $possible_answer_model = ClassRegistry::init('PossibleAnswer');
        $question_model = ClassRegistry::init('Question');
        $order_model = ClassRegistry::init('Order');

        $order = $order_model -> find('first', array(
        'Order.question_set_id' => $question_set_id,
        'Order.value' => $order_value));

        $question = $question_model -> find('first', array(
        'Question.id' => $order['Order']['question_id']));

        $this -> set('question', $question);

        if ($question['Question']['kind'] != "o") {
            $this -> set('possible_answers', $possible_answer_model -> find('all', array(
            'PossibleAnswer.question_id' => $question['Question']['id'])));
        }
.
.
.
```

What I get is:

> Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for AnswersController::add() [APP\Controller\AnswersController.php, line 10]
>
> Warning (2): Missing argument 2 for AnswersController::add() [APP\Controller\AnswersController.php, line 10]
>
> Warning (2): Missing argument 3 for AnswersController::add() [APP\Controller\AnswersController.php, line 10]

My link is:

> /answers/add/?customer_id=1&question_set_id=1&order_value=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link needs to be

```
/answers/add/1/1/1
```

in order to map to

```
AnswersController::add($customer_id, $question_set_id, $order_value)
```

Regular query parameters have to be accessed through `$this->params` inside the controller, they are not passed as arguments to the action.

Comment: Oh, I've found "my way" somewhere in the cookbook so I probably messed sth up - the link is now working but I'm getting "Undefined index" error at $customer_id = $this->params['url']['customer_id'] and the two other $this->params...

Comment: It's either or. If you don't pass them as `?customer_id=1` in the URL, they're not available in `$this->params`.

Comment: dont forget to make them `= null` by default to avoid warnings thrown!

Comment: @mark I don't want the page to run without these values so warnings are okay - I even have no index action, it's just one action, managed by my software

Comment: thing is, they url could be triggered without arguments from just about anybody - you should catch this in your controller instead. but the warnings thrown are unnecessary either way, and therefore my hint!

Comment: @mark I'm on the side of Szymon here, if the arguments are required and there should be no link without them, it's not incorrect to trigger warnings. In debug=0 mode they're not shown anyway, so no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function add($customer_id=null, $question_set_id=null, $order_value=null) {
  ....
 }
```

Probably aren't passing the arguments  you need to when it's required, you can just do the above and it won't require it.

Comment: sorry, now I've edited my question, I showed the link by witch I'm trying to pass these arguments (which are necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using custom routes, and this solve for me.

```
Router::connect('/me/edit/:id', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'),
        array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+')
    );
```

Thanks for @david-yell in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989140/1424473.