# Make Cakephp urls more SEO friendly

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.0

I know this question is been asked several times, and I went through all other solutions, but I could do not solve the issue.

https://www.example.com/cars/view/161/BMW-X5

to be

https://www.example.com/cars/161/BMW-X5

my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')); 
    Router::connect('/admin',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CakePHP - How to make routes with custom parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976578/cakephp-how-to-make-routes-with-custom-parameters)

Comment: @Machavity, Thanks. but the example is not the same as mine, I am looking for a simple solution without any tokens. just if you can help me and provide me with the code based on my code above, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect with

```
Router::connect('/cars/*', array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view'));
```

`CarsController::view()` will receive single argument, which should be used to find car by name.

Link with `$this->Html->link('My Link', array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view', $slug));`

For more route components, you need to use named parameters:

```php
Router::connect('/cars/:id/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view'],
    [
        // :id parameter will be passed as argument of CarsController::view()
        'pass' => ['id']
    ]
);
```

Link with `$this->Html->link('My Link', array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug));`

Comment: It worked, but if I want to have https://www.example.com/cars/161/BMW-X5/model-2019? How should I make /cars/:id/:slug ?

Comment: Just add more parameters: `/cars/:id/:make/:model`